# POSTGRESQL: Generate series between a column 'date_to' and column 'date_from' that they already exist in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have this problem: I have a table with columns that are an article and a date from and a date to (which is a time interval),

I already create this query in sql developer but i would like to know how to translated to postgresql

```
select ITEM, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO, DATE_FROM + level - 1 as "date" from t
connect by level <= DATE_FROM - DATE_TO  + 1
    and prior ITEM = ITEM
and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

That query make the example written below:

```
ITEM   | DATE_FROM  | DATE_TO
IT_01  | 01/01/2021 | 07/01/2021
```

I would like to generate a query that generates a new column in which the interval from the date from and the date to is specified, generating the rows with the article of that interval, leaving the result like this:

```
ITEM    |  DATE_FROM    |    DATE_TO      |     DATE_PER_DAY
--------+---------------+-----------------+------------------    
IT_01   |  01/01/2021   |   07/01/2021    |   *01/01/2021*
IT_01   |  01/01/2021   |   07/01/2021    |   *02/01/2021*
IT_01   |  01/01/2021   |   07/01/2021    |   *03/01/2021*
IT_01   |  01/01/2021   |   07/01/2021    |   *04/01/2021*
IT_01   |  01/01/2021   |   07/01/2021    |   *05/01/2021*
IT_01   |  01/01/2021   |   07/01/2021    |   *06/01/2021*
IT_01   |  01/01/2021   |   07/01/2021    |   *07/01/2021*
```

Answer (score 0):

First off in Oracle your query would not generate what you claim. But converting to get the posted output is not complex. Postgres does not have `connect by` clause but it has a function [generate_series](https://dataschool.com/learn-sql/generate-series/) which can generate months directly. `Join lateral`  permits referencing the previous declared table in a sub-query. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d2cdc627efe3ddab12924dbafdfd44f3), somewhat extended).

```
select t.item, t.date_from, t.date_to, gs.gd::date
  from t 
  join lateral 
       ( select t.item,gd
           from generate_series ( t.date_from 
                                , t.date_to
                                , interval '1 month'
                                ) gd
        ) gs 
     on t.item = gs.item
```